# How to style radio box with image and without any labels

Tags: html, css

I have a table which a column of this table is only radio boxes.
I want to style the radio box with the following images:
http://i66.tinypic.com/28ipw1s.png
http://i64.tinypic.com/2ur1b88.png

or just style it so it will look normal and not the default styling of the browser.
The problem is that the solution for display the images above can be achieve by using labels and labels take space in the table which I don't want to give up.
This is my table:
[image]

I can't add any labels and I don't want any label next to my radiobox.
This is the solution which I am familiar which doesn't work with empty labels.

```
input[type="radio"]{
        width: 28px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    input[type="radio"]+label{
        display: inline-block;
        padding-left: 28px;
        line-height: 24px;
        background: url(http://i66.tinypic.com/28ipw1s.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    }

    input[type="radio"]:checked + label{
        background: url(http://i64.tinypic.com/2ur1b88.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    }
```

Comment: You can style the label you want to...

Comment: yea but it will take space inside my table and this is my first problem. I want to use empty label but all solutions works only with non empty labels.

Comment: An image takes space as well, but I believe there's a way that when using the label, it is actually occupying the same space as the radio button/image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  width: 17px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: url(http://i66.tinypic.com/28ipw1s.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance:none;
  -moz-appearance:none; 
  display: inline-block;
  height: 17px; 
  outline:none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked {
  background: url(http://i64.tinypic.com/2ur1b88.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="" value="">
```

Comment: Why not pure CSS? The image is not that complex to achieve with just CSS.

Comment: I am not the question maker ;)

Comment: I know, but you *could* suggest that to the question maker in order to make the web better.